# Why are my Mac Calendar alerts not popping but silently sitting in the Notification Center?

Tags: macos, notifications, calendar

I feel sorry for asking such a basic question.
I used to have a banner appearing in the top right corner alerting me.

I don't receive those notifications anymore since I did a clean install of my operating system.

My Calendar view with three alerts set:

[image: Calendar event view with alert]

---

The notification gets in the Notification Center, but I have to **click** on the date (top right corner) to see it.
This defeats the purpose of the notification (am I supposed to click every minute to see if I have a new notification?)

[image: I can see the alert after I click]

---

My Calendar settings:

[image: Calendar settings]

---

My System Preferences settings:

[image]

---

I don't even get notified with sound, although I checked the option "Play sound for notification"

Am I the only one facing this issue?

Answer (score 6):

I finally found the solution,
I had to tick the last checkbox from the notification settings: "When mirroring or sharing the display".
I now receive all notification messages again, including the ones from Calendar.

[image]

I guess this is because I sometimes use an external display, but the tricky thing is, this was affecting me even when I didn't have any external display plugged in.

Comment: The next question would then be : Why is it affecting you when you didn't have an external display plugged in? :)